# How to get a current port no. in which my device is connected...?

Tags: java, rxtx

I am trying to develop a application in java (Swing) in which I have to get and store that
event coming from device in database. I used RXTX to find all port which is in use but I want only that port in which my device is connected . I used a prolific driver.

```
private void findPorts() {
  Enumeration<CommPortIdentifier> portEnum =
    CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
  int portCount = 0;

  while ( portEnum.hasMoreElements() ) {
    portIdentifier = portEnum.nextElement();

    // populate the portNames array for display in gui.jcbPort
    //if the port is a serial port
    if(portCount < portNames.length &&
       portIdentifier.getPortType() == portIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
    {
      //put it in the array
      portNames[portCount] = portIdentifier.getName();
      portCount++;                
    }
  }        
}
```

Comment: please retag this question, it has nothing to do with swing... you propably have to read the driver's documentation

Comment: Post some code snippets, like what you have tried. You need to show you have done some research and put some effort before asking a question.

Comment: Here is my code it gives me all port which is used but i want a particular port in which my device is connected and i used a pl2303 prolific drivet for my usb device ...@RahulGogo`                                                                                                                           ------------------

Comment: @KumarGaurav there was a similar question/solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6362775/getting-device-driver-information-related-to-a-com-port